# Error "net.:ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME" while trying to join a zoom meeting in ionic in-app-browser

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, inappbrowser, zoom-sdk

I'm trying to join a zoom meeting using the InAppBrowser plugin and  I get the following error:

> The webpage at zoomus://us05web.zoom.us/join? could not be loaded because: net.:ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Here's the relevant code in my Ionic component:

```
import { Component, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser/ngx';

import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(
    private iab: InAppBrowser,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
    ) {}

  openTikTokVideo() {
    const tiktokUrl = 'https://us05web.zoom.us';

    const sanitizedUrl = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL, this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(tiktokUrl));
    
    const browser = this.iab.create(sanitizedUrl!, '_blank', {
      location: 'no',
      zoom: 'no'
    });

    browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
      browser.insertCSS({ code: "body{color: red;}" });
    });
  }
}
```